# Checking a bound on the Stieltjes transform from Terence Tao's notes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, integral-transforms, random-matrices

I'm trying to check a bound on [Stieltjes transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation) of a probability measure, that's given in equation (2.92) on P. 170 in Terence Tao's notes "[Topics in Random Matrix Theory](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf)". Denote the Stieltjes transform of the probability measure $\mu$ by $s_{\mu}(z)$. Then the bound mentioned in his notes is:

$zs_{\mu}(z)= 1 + o_{\mu}(z)$ as $z= x+iy \to \infty$ so that $|\frac{x}{y}|$ is bounded. N.B. here "$o_{\mu}(z)$" is a notation used to denote $o(z)$ but with highlighting the fact that $z=x+iy\to \infty$ with $|x/y|$ bounded, and that the convergence rate depends on $\mu$.

But all I'm getting, at least under a special case, is: under the same condition of convergence, mentioned just now, $zs_{\mu}(z)= -1 + o_{\mu}(z)$, which I demonstrate below.

For the special case that I'll treat, just assume that: $\frac{x}{y}=K$. But if you follow my computation below, you'll see that the end result wouldn't change in the limit if you assume $|\frac{x}{y}|\leq K$.

$$zs_{\mu}(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{z}{t-z}d\mu(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{z(t-\bar{z})}{|t-z|^2}d\mu(t)= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{(tx - x^2 - y^2)+i(ty)}  {(t-x)^2 + y^2 }d\mu(t)=  \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{(\frac{x}{y}.\frac{t}{y}- (\frac{x}{y})^2-1) + i(\frac{t}{y})}{(\frac{x}{y})^2+1}d\mu(t)= -1 + \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{K+1}{K^2 + 1}\frac{t}{y}d\mu(t)= -1 + \frac{K+1}{K^2 + 1}.\frac{\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}]}{y}$$, where  $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}]$ is really the expectation of the identity function $\mathbb{I}(t):=t$ w.r.t. $\mu$. *Assume it exists for now!*

Note that, above, since $z=x+iy \to \infty$ but $|x/y|$ is bounded (actually I assumed that  $|x/y|$ is constant to make things bit easy), we must have $y \to \infty$, yielding:

$zs_{\mu}(z)= -1 + o_{\mu}(z)$, disproving $zs_{\mu}(z)= 1 + o_{\mu}(z)$. *Did I do something wrong in my calculation?*

**Also note that:** if you take: $\mu$ to be the Dirac measure at $0$, i.e. $\mu = \delta_0$, then $s_{\mu}(z)= -1/z$, **which does satisfy: $zs_{\mu}(z)= -1 + o_{\mu}(z)$, but not $zs_{\mu}(z)= 1 + o_{\mu}(z)$.**

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Tao defines $X = o(Y)$ by the requirement $|X|≤c(n)Y$. Note the modulus on the left side. I think the equation $s_\mu = \frac{1 + o_\mu (z)}{z}$ on P. 170 should accordingly be interpreted as $\vert z s_\mu (z) - 1 \vert = o_\mu (z)$.

Comment: @BrunoKrams Thanks, but Tao writes on P.170: "...where $o_{\mu}(z)$ is an expression that, for any fixed $\mu$, goes to zero as
$z\to\infty$ non-tangentially in the sense that $|Re(z)/Im(z)|$
is kept bounded, where the rate of convergence is allowed to depend
on  $\mu$". Did I miss something? Where did you find that definition of "o" in Tao's book?

Also, does your comment contradict $zs_{\mu}(z) + 1 =o_{\mu}(z) ?$ Following Tao's notation of $o_{\mu}(z) $, I did interpret it exactly as you wrote:
$|zs_{\mu}(z) - 1| =o_{\mu}(z) $. Still, the counterexamples I gave above are valid.

Comment: The definition can be found on page 6.
If the o-Notation is interpreted as I wrote, than what you gave is not a counterexample but in perfect agreement with the equation (2.92) from Tao's book. Also your calculation is - with slight modifications - a proof of (2.92) :)

Comment: By the way on page 169 Tao himself gives the series expansion $$s_n(z) = - \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z^2} \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{tr} M_n - ...$$ so it would be a very surprising mistake if he missed a sign in (2.92) on the next page.

Comment: Sorry, I just looked at Page 6. He defined there something entirely different: he's talking about the dimension $n$ of random matrices there, which, in my question itself, is not relevant at all. My question concerns not random matrix, so you can ignore that definition of $o$, and consider that of $o_{\mu}$ that he writes on P.170, specially related to my questions.

Also, could you please be so kind to point out why my calculation and counterexamples aligns with $zs_{\mu}(z)= 1 + o_{\mu}(z)$? 

In fact, I totally agree with what he wrote on P.169, because it validates my calculation.

Comment: @BrunoKrams Please feel free to suggest an edit to my calculation. Honestly, I strongly think he missed a sign on P.170. Your second comment on his expression on P.169 validates my calculation: notice the $-1/z$ there, but doesn't validate (2.92), for which it has to be $1/z$. If you correct me on that, I'd appreciate if you please be detailed.

Comment: Maybe, I was a bit hasty with what I wrote in my first comment. Rather than $\vert z s_\mu (z) - 1 \vert = o_\mu (1)$ it should be read as $\vert s_\mu \vert = \frac{1 + o_\mu (1) }{z}$. The definition I'm refering to is 1.1.2. Maybe it's on another page (allthough I used the source in your link).

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a minor typo in the definition of the Stieltjes transform on page 169 of those notes, namely instead of
$$
s_\mu(z):=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{x-z}d\mu(x),\qquad \Im z>0
$$
the intended definition is
$$
s_\mu(z):=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{z-x}d\mu(x),\qquad \Im z>0.
$$
After fixing the sign mistake caused by swapping $x$ and $z$, this matches the [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation) and also allows a straightforward justification of $(2.92)$ on page 170 as follows. Let $z_n$ be any sequence of complex numbers with $\Im(z_n)>0$ such that $z_n\to\infty$ non-tangentially, and let $f_n(x)=(z_n-x)^{-1}$. Then for all $x\in\mathbb R$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}z_nf_n(x)=1,
$$
thus by the dominated convergence theorem it follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}z_ns_{\mu}(z_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R}z_nf_n(x)d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}\lim_{n\to \infty}z_nf_n(x)d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}d\mu(x)=1,
$$
which in Tao's notation is equivalent to stating that $zs_{\mu}(z)=1+o_{\mu}(1)$, as claimed.

Note that the applicability of the dominated convergence theorem is justified in the exact same manner as in the observation $(2.91)$ on page 170, since the integrand satisfies
$$
|z_nf_n(x)|\leq \frac{|z_n|}{|\Im(z_n)|}\leq 1.
$$
In other words, we are actually using the special case of the dominated convergence theorem known as the [bounded convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235511/explanation-of-the-bounded-convergence-theorem).

Comment: thanks for your answer. But the definitions of Stieltjes transform seems to vary quite bit, without affecting the main results upto a sign change it seems: see this very early paper - https://www.jstor.org/stable/1989901?seq=1 (look at the preview), the wiki definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation) that you already pointed out, Silverstein's definition (http://www.ims.nus.edu.sg/Programs/randommatrix/files/jsilverstein_ln.pdf) and so on. But the other results on P. 169 of Tao's notes are soncistent with (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{d\mu(t)}{t-z}$, because look at the equation right after "Whereas the moment method started from the identity (2.83), the
Stieltjes transform method proceeds from the identity" on P.169: it'd be $\frac{1}{n}tr((zI - \frac{M_n}{\sqrt(n)})^{-1})$ had he defined the transform same as wiki's defintion  (the one you used). Also in the analytic expression, see that the leading term is $\frac{-1}{z}$ in Tao's notes, which'd be $\frac{1}{z}$ , had he defined using the one you mentioned. 

But I guess we both agree that at least either way, there's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late but maybe this can help:

Though this is not part of the OP, it is mentioned in T. Tao's notes and I will show a short proof of some facts:

- Analyticity of the Stieltjes transform:

Let $\mu$ be a complex measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, and suppose $\operatorname{sup}(\mu)=\Omega$ so that  $D=\mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega$ is open.

Then, the map
$f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ given by
$$
\begin{align}
f(z)= \int_\Omega\frac{\mu(d\omega)}{\omega-z}\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
$$
is analytic. Moreover, if the closed ball  $\overline{B}(a;r)\subset D$, then
$$
\begin{align}
f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_n(z-a)^n,\qquad z\in B(a;r)\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
c_n=\int_\Omega\frac{\mu(d\omega)}{(\omega-a)^{n+1}},\qquad
|c_n|\leq \frac{\|\mu\|_{TV}}{r^{n+1}},\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}_+.\tag{3}\label{three}
\end{align}
$$
If $R$ is the radius of convergence of $\eqref{two}$, then $r\leq R$.
Here is a short proof:

If  $\overline{B}(a;r)\subset D$, then
$q:=\inf_{\omega\in\Omega}|\omega-a|>r$, and so
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{|z-a|}{|\omega-a|}\leq \frac{|z-a|}{q}\leq\frac{r}{q}<1,\qquad
\omega\in\Omega,\quad z\in B(a;r).
\end{align}
$$
Hence, for any $z\in B(a;r)$ fixed,  the series
$$
\omega\mapsto
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(z-a)^n}{(\omega-a)^{n+1}}
=\frac{1}{\omega-z}
$$
converges absolutely and uniformly in $\Omega$. By  **dominated convergence** (to justify change of order of summation and integration)
$$
f(z)=\int_\Omega \frac{\mu(d\omega)}{\omega-z}=
\int_\Omega \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(z-a)^n}{(\omega-a)^{n+1}}
 \,\mu(d\omega)
= \sum^\infty_{n=0}c_n(z-a)^n,
$$
where the $c_n$ satisfy $\eqref{three}$. The last statement follows from the estimate
$$\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{r}\sqrt[n]{\frac{\|\mu\|_{TV}}{r}}=\frac{1}{r}
\end{align}
$$

- Non tangential asymptotyics. Suppose $|z|\rightarrow\infty$ over a region of the form $T_M=\{z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}:|x|\leq M|y|\}\setminus\Omega$ for some fixed $M>0$. Then
  $$
  \Big|\frac{z}{\omega-z}\Big|\leq\frac{|z|}{||z|-|\omega||}\xrightarrow{|z|\rightarrow\infty}1
  $$
  for each $\omega\in\Omega$, and
  $$
  \Big|\frac{z}{\omega-z}\Big|\leq\frac{|x|+|y|}{|y|}\leq M+1
  $$
  for all $\omega\in\Omega$. Then, by dominated convergence, letting $z\rightarrow\infty$ over the region $T_M$
  $$
  zf(z)=\int_\Omega\frac{z}{\omega-z}\,\mu(d\omega)\xrightarrow{|z|\rightarrow\infty}\mu(\Omega)
  $$
- If $\mu$ has compact support, then the asymptotic may be improved considerably . Let $M=\sup\{|\omega|:\omega\in \Omega\}$. Then
  $$
  \frac{1}{\omega-z}=-\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\tfrac{\omega}{z}}=-\frac{1}{z}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{\omega^n}{z^n}
  $$
  By dominated convergence

$$
f(z)=-\frac{1}{z}\sum^\infty_{k=0}z^{-n}\int_\Omega \omega^n\,\mu(d\omega)
$$

Hence

$$zf(z)=\mu(\Omega) +z^{-1}\int_\Omega \omega\,\mu(d\omega) +o_\mu(z^{-1})
$$